# JMeter distribution load testing Error: Connection refused to host

Tags: jmeter, connection

We are facing issues in JMeter remote testing. Master is stuck at:

> Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/Heapdump message on port 4445

While the client is throwing:

> Connection refused to host exception

We are running master like below:

```
.\jmeter  <b>-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.19.120.43 </b> -n -t .\Test.jmx -R 10.75.225.188
```

But in the slave side test completion status is sent to some other IP address:

```
2020-06-11 15:54:01,788 INFO o.a.j.e.RemoteJMeterEngineImpl: Creating JMeter engine on host 10.75.225.188 base '.'
<br>2020-06-11 15:54:01,788 INFO o.a.j.e.RemoteJMeterEngineImpl:<b> Remote client host: 10.19.120.43</b>
<br>2020-06-11 15:54:01,788 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Set new base='.'
<br>2020-06-11 15:54:01,793 INFO o.a.j.e.RemoteJMeterEngineImpl: Cleaning previously set properties: {sample_variables=ulp_buffer_fill,ulp_lag_time,ulp_play_time,ulp_lag_ratio,ulp_dwn_time,ulp_hits,ulp_avg_chunk_time,ulp_avg_manifest_time}
2020-06-11 15:54:01,794 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Applying properties {sample_variables=ulp_buffer_fill,ulp_lag_time,ulp_play_time,ulp_lag_ratio,ulp_dwn_time,ulp_hits,ulp_avg_chunk_time,ulp_avg_manifest_time}
<br>2020-06-11 15:54:01,795 INFO o.a.j.e.RemoteJMeterEngineImpl: Running test
<br>2020-06-11 15:54:01,797 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
<br>2020-06-11 15:54:01,797 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: [ulp_buffer_fill, ulp_lag_time, ulp_play_time, ulp_lag_ratio, ulp_dwn_time, ulp_hits, ulp_avg_chunk_time, ulp_avg_manifest_time]
<br>2020-06-11 15:54:22,801 ERROR o.a.j.s.RemoteListenerWrapper: testStarted(host) on 10.75.225.188
java.rmi.ConnectException: <b>Connection refused to host: 10.0.75.1; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect </b>
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy20.testStarted(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.RemoteListenerWrapper.testStarted(RemoteListenerWrapper.java:79) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.notifyTestListenersOfStart(StandardJMeterEngine.java:217) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:384) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_231]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
    ... 11 more
```

**FYI: this machine has docker running on it and 10.0.75.1 is associated with it**

Answer (score 0):

You need to [EXPOSE](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose) port 1099 (or whatever port you're using as the `server_port`) in your [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) (or use [`host` network driver](https://docs.docker.com/network/#network-drivers)) and in the firewall of your 10.75.225.188 machine, this is the minimum requirement for JMeter master could establish the connectivity with the slave machine.

More information: [Remote hosts and RMI configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote)

You can also refer to [JMeter Distributed Testing with Docker](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-distributed-testing-with-docker) article, it has some sample [networking configuration](https://docs.docker.com/network/) you might be willing to apply to your system